# How do I change a salesperson's permissions so he can't modify sales prices in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

We have an OpenERP instance set up but there is some tweaking to do still.

The most important one is that our salespersons have access to modify the product's base sales price and we need to prevent this from happening.

I can see the Users section on the left and see each user.  That particular user appears as:

```
Sales Management: Manager
Project Management: Manager
Warehouse Management: User
Accounting Finance: Accountant
Purchase Requisition: Manager
Purchase Management: Manager
Human Resources: Employee
Administration: Access Rights
```

Which needs to be eliminated of modified such that the salespersons are not able to modify Base Sales Prices?

Comment: What I suggestion in this, create a new access right under Users => Access Right => Technical Settings => (like Modify Sale Price) if that is checked than in product form sale price field is visible otherwise hidden. So user can not see that field and can not modified. If User has Modify Sale Price checked than field is visible and can be modify if needed.

Comment: There is no such thing as Modify Sale Price in Access Rights of Users in Settings.  Just those options mentioned in my original question.